# Emulate CHMOD in Windows PHP development

Tags: php, wamp, file-permissions, chmod, emulation

I'm developing file management wares on my Windows dev box. Dreading the day when I start testing it in remote LAMP environment; bouncing my head off a thousand potential CHMOD issues. ‡

I know that PHP's read/write file/dir permission checks are ignored on Windows. However, I'd like to **emulate** it. Has anyone thought of doing this before? What I have in mind is cooking up the following:

- Route all permission-related functions via proxy functions that simply pass through to the default functions on *nix -- but emulate CHMOD permission checks on Windows.
- Keep a record of all the "virtual" permissions set by these functions, against which all permission-related file and directory transactions are cleared.
- All these virtual permissions would have no impact on the actual Windows filesystem. This setup would exist merely to emulate what happens when we're on *nix.

Does that make any sense? Or am I wasting my time with the idea? A setup like this would also make it possible to "shuffle" file permissions to random, prepping up a litmus buffet of test cases.

(N.B. I'm not looking into installing a *nix VM on my dev laptop at this time. It'd certainly be a fine way to do all this filesystem related testing locally. But not just for tackling this case.)

‡ *Just so it's perfectly clear. I am not an alien to file permissions. The issue is over developing software on a platform that doesn't give you the expected feedback when code is executed.*

Comment: But.. but... _why_ ???

Comment: Well why do people emulate other platforms. So I can do the whole lot using one development setup, and eliminate much of the remote *nix testing loop. For an additional incentive for this, in these parts of the backwoods the nets are pretty dreadful, and even if I spent a jolly day or two hacking this together, it would be a good deal less than the time that'd likely go into permission debugging back-and-forths with the *nix box over time... Does that make sense. It does to me.

Comment: I have no problems with *nix environments. However, this one laptop I have is used for a lot of stuff besides hacking code. Much of it won't get done on a *nix setup because suitable software n/a. So I use Windows on my laptop. I'm looking for smooth cross-platform development solutions, dealing with the platform I need to use.